# Aloha Editor Configuration

Tags: javascript, css, aloha-editor

I am currently using the Aloha Editor and I'm trying to customize a few things.

I'm trying to make it so that it will auto-pin to a certain area rather than just right above the textarea.

I'm also trying to disable certain plugins inside the toolbar so that users can use it at all.

Any idea how I would go about doing this? Can't find much online and the aloha editor isn't very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo configuration: https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/blob/release/src/demo/boilerplate/js/aloha-config.js

And here how to auto-pin the toolbar: https://getsatisfaction.com/aloha_editor/topics/make_toolbar_fixed_no_float_effect_and_shown_at_page_load#reply_9970928